# Flutter/dart: is there a way to convert json to xml?

Tags: json, xml, flutter, dart

There's a flutter package (xml2json) for converting xml to json, but not the other way around, json to xml. Is there a difficulty in making an algorithm that solves this? There are plenty of online json-xml converters, but no implementation for flutter

Comment: There's no difficulty devising an algorithm that converts JSON to XML or vice versa (in fact I would say JSON to XML is easier). But there's immense difficulty in devising an algorithm that meets the requirements of all the potential users. Because in the end, you don't just want any old JSON, you want JSON that's usable.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, I didn't know, but there is a way to build xml with flutter xml package

Answer (score 2):

I found that the [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) package has a function for building xml, eg:

```
final builder = XmlBuilder();
builder.processing('xml', 'version="1.0"');
builder.element('bookshelf', nest: () {
  builder.element('book', nest: () {
    builder.element('title', nest: () {
      builder.attribute('lang', 'en');
      builder.text('Growing a Language');
    });
    builder.element('price', nest: 29.99);
  });
  builder.element('price', nest: '132.00');
});
final document = builder.buildDocument();
```

So, in my situation, I just had to instantiate the `XmlBuilder()`, start `builder.processing('xml', 'version="1.0"');`, cicle through my json file with foreach, and insert the json key/values to xmlbuilder tree, and finalize with `builder.buildDocument()`